# Text Mining with Pubmed Widget Orange

Tags: text-mining, orange, information-retrieval

When I was running the text mining I did not have an issue for 57 different searches. I was able to retrieve all of the records regardless of how many there were.
Until these 2 errors popped up.

I also went back and tried previous searches that worked fine and this issues poped up.

I tried running the same search on a different computer and did not run into this issue.

I have already uninstalled and reinstalled the program twice with no change.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have found clearing the cache for orange fixed this.

Comment: Really? Which cache specifically? Because there doesn't seem to be one specifically for PubMed.